# How to compare one month-with-day to another in Java?

Tags: java, spring, date, simpledateformat

I want to compare two date one is to take as current date and another one is static date that is from local variable. I want to compare date and month only i have written one program can anyone confirm is it right or not ?

````
String str="27/09";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String date1=dtf.format(now);
        
        System.out.println("fist date Date 1\t"+date1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
        Date d1 = sdformat.parse(str);
        String date2=sdformat.format(d1);
        System.out.println("second date Date2 \t"+date2);
        
        int result = date1.compareTo(date2);

        if (result < 0) {
            System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
        }```

LOCALDATE>STATICVARIABLE DATE this is condition and want to compare date and month only.
````

Comment: Try to avoid using `java.util.Date` and the related API and get familiar with the classes in `java.time` instead. That's a much better and easier to use API. You've already started doing so by using `LocalDateTime` so just parse the date the user entered and then compare, e.g. by parsing it to `LocalDate` which you then convert to `LocalDateTime` by using the methods `atStartOfDay()` or `atTime(...)`. Finally check both dates using `isBefore()` or `isAfter()`.

Comment: i don't want to use api just want to compare current dd/mm > local variable dd/mm. can you write simple program for this

Comment: Instead of comparing dates, try to compare using milliseconds. I think it will help to solve your problem.

Comment: 1. Current Date 2.Date from local variable         but i want to compare dd/mm(1)>dd/mm(2)

Comment: "just want to compare current dd/mm > local variable dd/mm" - for that you need to use the date api. Note that if you want to only compare days and not time as well, use something like `parsedLocalDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())`. Or do you want to compare only day and month without the year? In that case I'd suggest getting both dates and then comparing month and day separately.

Comment: yes want to compare without year. Can you please write program for this in java

Comment: Have a look at methods like `LocalDate.getMonthValue()`, `LocalDate.getDayOfMonth()`, `Comparator.comparing()` and `Comparator.thenComparing()`, e.g. to get a comparator for both `LocalDate` instances try `Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::getMonthValue).thenComparing(LocalDate::getDayOfMonth)`.

Comment: Is `31/12` before or after `01/01`?

Comment: yes you are write but how to write function for this ?

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay
.of( Month.OCTOBER , 1 ) 
.isAfter( 
    MonthDay
    .parse(
        "27/09" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" ) 
    )
)
```

Run this code [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ykM8Iv).

> true

## `java.time.MonthDay`

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

For a day of month, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( 9 , 27 ) ;
```

For exchanging date-time values as text, ask the publisher of your data to use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For month-day, that format is `--MM-DD`.

```
String output = md.toString() ;
```

> --09-27

If you must accept non-standard input, define a formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" ) ;
```

Parse your input.

```
String input = "27/09" ;
MonthDay sept27 = MonthDay.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> sept27.toString(): --09-27

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ykM8Iv).

You can compare `MonthDay` objects by using their methods [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#isBefore(java.time.MonthDay)), `equals`, and `isAfter`.

If you want the current year-month, you need to a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. So near the start/end of a month, it might be “next” month in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “previous” month in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
MonthDay currentYearMonth = MonthDay.now( z ) ;
```